# Error Mysqli mysqli_query() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli, incluso si ya le estoy dando los dos parametros que pide

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

Tengo este código:

```
<?php
    require ("../clases/Conexion.php");

    session_start();
         $host = "localhost:3307";
         $user = "root";
         $pass = "";
         $bd = "nutricion";
         $con = mysqli_connect($host,$user,$pass,$bd) or die("Error al conectar al Servidor");
         $con = new conexion();
        $con->conectar();

    if ($_SESSION["correo"]=='') {
        //header("Location:../index.php");  exit;
        echo "1";
    }
    $msql_db_query= mysqli_query($bd,"SELECT * FROM tbl_usuario WHERE correo='" . $_SESSION['correo'] . "';") or die ("Error al buscar usuario");
    if ($result) {
        $id_usuario = mysqli_result($msql_db_query(),0,'id');
        $nombre_usuario = mysqli_result($msql_db_query(),0,'nombre') . " " . mysqli_result($msql_db_query(),0,'apellido');
     }else {
        //header("Location:../index.php");  exit;
        echo "2";
    }

    date_default_timezone_set('America/Mexico_City');
    ?>
```

El cual me genera el siguiente error:

> Warning: mysqli_query() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli, object given in C:\xampp\htdocs\admin\clases\Acceso.php on line 17
>   Error al buscar usuario

He buscado en internet cuál sería la solución pero no logro encontrarlo, quería ver si alguno podría ayudarme verificando mi código. Se supone que después de pasar por el login debería de pasar a otra página, antes si funcionaba, pero ahora ya no.

Intente todas las sufgerencias que me fueron hechas, las que encontre en internet y nada me funciona, no entiendo porque me sale ese error si realmente le estoy dando los 2 parametros que me pide.

Comment: Hola Analy, te damos la bienvenida a Stack Overflow en español. Aunque la pregunta es interesante y se ajusta al formato, [ya se se ha realizado en numerosas ocasiones y tiene respuesta en el sitio](https://es.stackoverflow.com/search?q=%22mysqli_query%28%29+expects+parameter+1+to+be+mysqli%22). Lee [ask] para más información y sigue los consejos que encontrarás allí. Un saludo.

Answer (score 2):

**OBSERVACIONES**

Dentro de tu consulta SQL, debes pasar primero la variable de conexión no la variable que tiene el nombre de tu base de datos

Debería quedar así

```
$msql_db_query= mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM tbl_usuario WHERE correo='" . $_SESSION['correo'] . "';") 
or die ("Error al buscar usuario");
```

Otra cosa creo que usas POO al momento de hacer lo sigueinte:

```
 $con = new conexion();
    $con->conectar();
```

> Si haces lo anterior no tienes por que redeclarar la conexión completa
>   pues se supone que ya lo hiciste en el archivo que se llama
>   Conexion.php; revisa eso
>
> Elimina la conexión que tienes repetida en tu archivo que muestras
>   puesto que por la lógica que tienes ya viene del archivo de Conexion

Comment: Oye sí, está extraño eso, que pareciera que "se conecta" 2 veces... de pronto es por los intentos que ha hecho para que funcione, y se le fue ese código en el copy paste al post :o

Comment: precisamente por eso le hago la observación @quinqui para que elimine ese error

Comment: Esta respuesta parece un poco de especulación, `$con` en ese momento no parece ser una conexión mysqli, por lo que seguramente el usuario recibiría el mismo error (aunque eso dependería del contenido de Conexion.php que desconocemos).

Comment: De echo esa parte la tenía comentada y de igual manera me tiraba un error, este código me funcionaba perfectamente hace dos años, ahorita muchas partes del código están insersibles, pero sigo sin poder hacer funcionar la conexion, tengo el código anterior de la conexión y me sale  este error

Warning: mysqli_connect(): (HY000/2002): No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it. in C:\xampp\htdocs\admin\clases\Conexion.php on line 10
Error al conectar al Servidor

Comment: con el nuevo código me sale el error con el cual pedí ayuda, se los comparto en el primer post para ver si pueden ayudarme.

Answer (score 2):

Bienvenid@, Analy. El error te dice que la función `mysqli_query` espera que en el primer parámetro coloques el objeto de conexión a tu base de datos, y tú le estás enviando el nombre de la base de datos.

En tu código, te falta almacenar en alguna variable la acción que haces para conectarte, que seguramente es en `$con->conectar();`.

Te sugiero a cambiar a algo como esto, y nos cuentas si te sirvió:

```
$link = $con->conectar();

$msql_db_query= mysqli_query($link, "SELECT * FROM tbl_usuario WHERE correo='" . $_SESSION['correo'] . "';") or die ("Error al buscar usuario");
```

Comment: Esta respuesta parece más bien especulación, ¿cómo sabes que `$con->conectar()` devuelve una conexión mysqli en lugar de ser un objeto con una propiedad que haga de conexión? Y teniendo en cuenta que luego en el código usa funciones `mysqli_*` casi parecería que es la parte de `$con->conectar()` la que sobra y no al revés.

Comment: Efectivamente, no lo sé, y estoy especulando ¿Elimino mi respuesta?

Comment: No hace falta que la borres.

Comment: utilice tu solución y me salio este error

Warning: mysqli_query() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli, null given in C:\xampp\htdocs\admin\clases\Acceso.php on line 19

Comment: Analy, el "nuevo" error (_Warning: mysqli_connect(): (HY000/2002): No connection could be made because the..._) con el que actualizaste tu pregunta principal, ya es otro error, y sería bueno que lo publicaras como una nueva pregunta, en especial porque la actual (`Error Mysqli mysqli_query() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli`), te la han marcado como "ya respondida en otro post" (duplicada).