# No me puedo conectar con la base de datos

Tags: php, mysql, base-de-datos, mysqli

Tengo este código :

```
<?php

class Conexion {
    private $host = "localhost";
    private $user = "root";
    private $pass = "";
    private $bd = "nutricion";
    private $con;
    public function Conectar() {
        $this->con = mysqli_connect($this->host, $this->user) or die("Error al conectar al Servidor");
        mysql_select_db($this->bd, $this->con) or die("Ha ocurrido un Error al conectar a la Base de Datos");
    }
}

?>
```

El cuál me genera el siguiente error:

> Warning: mysqli_connect(): (HY000/2002): No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it. in C:\xampp\htdocs\admin\clases\Conexion.php on line 10 Error al conectar al Servidor

He probado nuevas formas de conectar la base de datos con otros códigos pero todos me generan error, hace dos años este código me funcionaba perfectamente, estoy retomando el proyecto y no soy nada buena con php, espero alguien pueda ayudarme.

Comment: Parece que las credenciales del servidor mysql son incorrectas, aunque es un error algo atípico el que muestras, ¿puedes conectar directamente con el cliente mysql o phpmyadmin? asegúrate que el usuario que usas tiene permisos apropiados y comprueba que puedes realmente conectar y realizar consultas de forma más directa.

Comment: para la conexion esta usando ``mysqli`` y para seleccionar la base de datos `mysql`, ese podria ser el error.

Comment: esta mezclando 2 drivers diferentes @track3r por eso el error, primero usa mysqli y luego mysql

Comment: Cierto! gracias por el apunte, se me pasó por alto. Me despistó lo de que hace años le funcionó.

Comment: Siii, lo sé de hecho ya modificado con mysqli en los dos, me sale el error, en el copy paste se me paso, pero todo lo que intento me sale un error, y siempre es el mismo 

Warning: mysqli_query() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli

coon este código me funcionaba hace dos años, ahora ya no funciona el mysql, así que lo cambie por mysqli y me genero ese otro error, la verdad ya no sé que hacer :C, estoy desesperada porque no encuentro una solución

Comment: que version de php estas usando??

Comment: intenta usando un `return` al momento de dar las ordenes a tu `public function` ej:  `return $this->con = mysqli_connect`...

Comment: Oh, @Mr.Manutri, tienes toda la razón, yo por mi parte editaré mi respuesta para incluir ese crucial detalle!! :o

Comment: El mensaje `No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it.` puede indicar un problema suplementario, por ejemplo, que algún corta fuegos está bloqueando la conexión o el puerto que usa la conexión, que el puerto de conexión no es el correcto o que has omitido el password.

Comment: Por ese error sugiero revisar el puerto de conexión de MySQL si esta escuchando o esta bloqueado.

Comment: I watch your error man is your connection and the var con xd

Answer (score 5):

Si tienes un problema con el uso de las librerías de mysql y mysqli, pero esas no son las razones por las que te esta mandando el error:

> Warning: mysqli_connect(): (HY000/2002): No connection could be made
>   because the target machine actively refused it. in
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\admin\clases\Conexion.php on line 10 Error al conectar
>   al Servidor

La razón de este error es por que el puerto del MySQL no lo estas accediendo, que puede ser por muchas razones, las que se me ocurren pueden ser por que se te esta bloqueando el puerto o por que el puerto no esta escuchando mas específicamente podrían ser:

- El MySQL esta apagado, revisa su estatus para asegurarte que este prendido.
- El MySQL no esta escuchando por el puerto que le estas indicando, el puerto por deafult es el 3306.
- Hay un Firewall bloqueando la comunicación local, si ambos están instalados en el host local y si es Linux busca en tu iptables, si es windows revisa la documentación de tu firewall, también podrías intentar establecer la conexión desde una terminal o consola directamente al servidor de MySQL.
- Hay un Firewall o un problema de ruteo en tu red que no te esta dejando llegar a tu MySQL, revisa desde consola o terminal acceder a tu MySQL.

Generalmente si tu código es el mismo y antes funcionaba y ahora ya no funciona es por que algo cambio en el entorno o por que hay una excepción que no se tomo en cuenta, tal vez que podría ser:

1. La actualización del software (PHP, MySQL, Servidor Web, etc)
2. La red cambio
3. Hay nuevo software

Por último si las credenciales fueran erróneas el error sería diferente indicando un problema del usuario y password, y si fuera por usar mal las funciones habría un error diferente por el "resource id" o por función depreciada.

Comment: Ese error que le arroja, ¿podría deberse también por fallar muchas veces la conexión, y que el server le "banée" el acceso? (me pareció excelente tu respuesta, muy ilustrativa :) ).

Comment: Gracias!!, Puede ser cierto lo del banneo, pero ya intentaste usar la terminal de comandos y con un cliente MySQL conectarte desde el servidor donde tienes tu código al servidor MySQL??

Comment: Hola, gracias por tu respuesta, el caso es que en la ultima parte de tu respuestaa dices lo de los cambios, de hecho se actualizo el software y el codigo lo cambie por lo nuevo que se usa, osea el mysql por mysqli y estoy usando un puerto diferente porque en el 3306 no me funcionaba el mysql, lo cambie por 3307, pero aun especificando en el codigo con localhost:3307 sigue sin funcionar,no sé que estoy haciendo mal, realmente soy demaciado novata en estos temas.

Comment: podrías checarme en este problema que me surge cuando especifico el puerto que estoy usando en el codigo, por favor. 

https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/157106/error-mysqli-mysqli-query-expects-parameter-1-to-be-mysqli

Answer (score 1):

Así tal cual el código te arrojará error porque estás mezclando 2 librerías o clases distintas a la hora de hacer la conexión: `mysqli` y `mysql`, esta última ya obsoleta.

La forma correcta de conectar usando la clase `mysqli` sería en tu caso:

```
public function Conectar() {
        $this->con = mysqli_connect($this->host, $this->user, $this->pass, $this->bd) or die("Error al conectar al Servidor");
        return $this->con; // << este detalle crucial faltaba: retornar el enlace al ejecutar el método (por @Mr.Manutri)
    }
```

Una buena práctica es siempre revisar la **documentación oficial** de los lenguajes para poder encontrar la respuesta a los errores; si después de eso no encuentras la respuesta, aplica Google (y StackOverflow :P ). 
Acá encuentras la de esta función en específico: [PHP: mysqli_connect](https://secure.php.net/manual/es/function.mysqli-connect.php).

**EDITADO**

Ahora, en cuanto a la ejecución de consultas SQL usando `mysqli`, nuevamente nos referimos a la documentación oficial: [PHP:mysqli_query](http://php.net/manual/es/mysqli.query.php)

El uso correcto de esta función es, asumiendo que estamos usando tu clase `Conexion`:

```
<?php
// Instancias el objeto:
$conexion = new Conexion();

// Ejecutas la conexión, y obtienes un identificador de enlace a la BD: 
// **FAVOR Notar el cambio que hice en tu declaración de método Conectar(), más arriba.
$enlace = $conexion->Conectar();

// Acá va tu query:
$consulta = "...";

// Y acá la ejecutas: debes incluir el identificador de enlace a la BD para que funcione correctamente:
$resultado = mysqli_query($enlace, $consulta);
?>
```

Pruébalo así, y nos cuentas.

Comment: Probando como me dices me sale el siguiente error, 

Warning: mysqli_query() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli, object given in C:\xampp\htdocs\admin\clases\Acceso.php on line 19

Comment: Mi respuesta fue para la parte de la conexión. Para la parte en que ejecutas el query, te edito mi respuesta.